# CPP / JUCE Audioprogramming Framework - Array of Sliders not working - Single Slider works

Tags: c++, arrays, audio, juce

i have some problems coding a custom component. However i tried with a single slider instance like this:

```
ScopedPointer<Slider> slider001;
ScopedPointer<Slider> slider002;

slider001->setBounds  (0        ,       sliderY , sliderWidth, sliderHeight );
slider002->setBounds  (0+ 1*sliderX ,   sliderY , sliderWidth, sliderHeight );

addAndMakeVisible (slider001 = new Slider ("new slider"));
addAndMakeVisible (slider002 = new Slider ("new slider"));
```

everything works as expected however you know people are lazy so i tried using an array:

```
ScopedPointer<Slider> sliderArray[128];


  for(int i=0; i==128; i++) 
{sliderArray[i]->setBounds  (0   +i  *sliderX    ,       sliderY , sliderWidth, sliderHeight );}


}                                     


for(int i=0; i==128; i++) 
{  
    addAndMakeVisible (sliderArray[i]= new Slider ("Value"));
    sliderArray[i]->setRange (sliderMinimumRange, sliderMaximumRange, sliderRangeStepsize );
    sliderArray[i]->setSliderStyle (Slider::LinearBarVertical);
}
```

now the screen just stays blank.
i tried replacing single slider elements with an array and iterating through them and i'm completely clueless where to start to fix this behaviour.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the way you have configured your loops:

```
for(int i=0; i==128; i++) {}
```

This can be interpreted as:

"set `i` to 0, and while `i == 128`, do `{}` then `i++`"

What you probably wanted to write was:

```
for(int i=0; i<128; i++) {}
```